# Can not overwrite file on linux

Tags: c++, file-permissions, iostream

I want to overwrite a file with restricted permissions.

`la -l` on the file:

```
-r--rw-r-- 1 simon filesystem 77 nov 27 17:56 00041_Alarm
```

I want to do it with the following executable (written in c++). The executable has the following permissions:

```
-rwxrwsr-x 1 simon filesystem 286296 nov 28 16:28 project_file*
```

I've set the sgid bit on the executable, I thought that meant that the executable ran as the group `filesystem` and that I could write file with that group.

I open the file and test if it's open but it prints a `0`, so not open:

```
std::ofstream file(filepath, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ofstream::trunc);
std::cout << file.is_open() << std::endl;
```

Comment: You missed to add the `id simon` information.

Comment: the group/setgid doesn't matter if the process is running as `simon`, because `simon` is the owner of the file and the `u+w` permission isn't set, so groups aren't even consulted. Counterintuitive, maybe, but true.

Comment: Also, a better test is to hardcode the name into the C++ code, not `filepath`.  You don't want to be embarrased if one of the reasons you are having an issue is that `filepath` is not correct.

Comment: What’s in filepath?